# Error in networking between containers after running docker compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Right now im on a journey of learning, so here I am bothering you all in order to figure out whats going on with my medusajs dockerized project.

After following the QuickStart guide, I was able to get my project built with docker compose build, however when running the project with docker compose up, it seem to be a issue with the communication between the front and the back container because I receive this error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000

If i make a test request from the command line to the container with the database listening in the port 9000 I receive a correct response, but the front container seem to be unable to contact the back container.

My docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.prod and docker-compose.override are as follow:

docker-compose.override

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./micruniverse-store-engine:/app/medusa
      - backend_node_modules:/app/medusa/node_modules
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  admin:
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"

  storefront:
    volumes:
      - ./micruniverse-storefront:/app/storefront
      - storefront_node_modules:/app/storefront/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

volumes:
  storefront_node_modules:
  backend_node_modules:
```

docker-compose.prod:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: backend:latest
    container_name: medusa-server
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/medusa-docker
      NODE_ENV: production
      STORE_CORS: "127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  postgres:
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: medusa-docker

  redis:
    restart: always

  admin:
    build:
      context: ./medusa-admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: admin:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    container_name: medusa-admin
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      NODE_OPTIONS: --openssl-legacy-provider
    ports:
      - "7000:80"

  storefront:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: storefront:latest
    container_name: medusa-storefront
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./micruniverse-store-engine
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: backend:test
    container_name: medusa-server
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/medusa-docker
      REDIS_URL: redis://cache
      NODE_ENV: development
      JWT_SECRET: some_jwt_secret
      COOKIE_SECRET: some_cookie_secret
      PORT: 9000

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: medusa-docker

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: cache
    expose:
      - 6379

  admin:
    build:
      context: ./medusa-admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: admin:test
    depends_on:
      - backend
    container_name: medusa-admin
    environment:
      NODE_OPTIONS: --openssl-legacy-provider

  storefront:
    build:
      context: ./micruniverse-storefront
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: storefront:test
    container_name: medusa-storefront
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

The error that I receive is as follow, after spinning up the project

```
sudo docker compose up
[+] Running 5/0
 ⠿ Container cache                Created                            0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusapr-postgres-1  Created                            0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-server        Creat...                           0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-storefront    C...                               0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-admin         Create...                          0.0s
Attaching to cache, medusa-admin, medusa-server, medusa-storefront, medusapr-postgres-1
cache                | 1:C 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.222 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
cache                | 1:C 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.222 # Redis version=7.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
cache                | 1:C 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.222 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.223 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.223 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 # Server initialized
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.0.4
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * RDB age 5 seconds
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * RDB memory usage when created 1.11 Mb
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 2, keys expired: 0.
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
cache                | 1:M 31 Jul 2022 22:56:22.224 * Ready to accept connections
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-31 22:56:22.353 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-31 22:56:22.353 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-31 22:56:22.356 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-31 22:56:22.374 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-07-31 22:56:17 UTC
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-31 22:56:22.380 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
medusa-admin         | node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
medusa-admin exited with code 9
medusa-server        | query: SELECT * FROM current_schema()
medusa-server        | query: SHOW server_version;
medusa-server        | query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = 'public' AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
medusa-server        | query: SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations" ORDER BY "id" DESC
medusa-server        | info:    Migrations completed.
medusa-server        | Successfully compiled 0 files with Babel (4ms).
medusa-server        | - Initializing models
medusa-server        | ✔ Models initialized – 46ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing plugin models
medusa-server        | ✔ Plugin models initialized – 5ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing repositories
medusa-server        | ✔ Repositories initialized – 77ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing database
medusa-server        | ✔ Database initialized – 235ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing strategies
medusa-server        | ✔ Strategies initialized – 18ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing services
medusa-server        | ✔ Services initialized – 182ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing express
medusa-server        | ✔ Express intialized – 15ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing plugins
medusa-server        | ✔ Plugins intialized – 265ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing subscribers
medusa-server        | ✔ Subscribers initialized – 14ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing API
medusa-server        | ✔ API initialized – 67ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing defaults
medusa-server        | warn:    You don't have any notification provider plugins installed. You may want to add one to your project.
medusa-server        | warn:    You don't have any taxProviders provider plugins installed. You may want to add one to your project.
medusa-server        | ✔ Defaults initialized – 313ms
medusa-server        | - Initializing search engine indexing
medusa-server        | warn:    No search engine provider was found: make sure to include a search plugin to enable searching
medusa-server        | ✔ Indexing completed – 20ms
medusa-server        | - Creating server
medusa-server        | ✔ Server is ready on port: 9000 – 56ms
medusa-storefront    | success compile gatsby files - 1.759s
success load gatsby config - 0.122s
success load plugins - 1.053s
success onPreInit - 0.006s
success initialize cache - 0.045s
success copy gatsby files - 0.174s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.290s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.320s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.012s
info Cache is warm, but incremental builds are currently not supported. Running
medusa-storefront    | a clean build.
info Initiating operation query products

medusa-storefront    |  ERROR
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | "The following error status was produced while attempting to fetch products:
medusa-storefront    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
medusa-storefront    | 

medusa-storefront    |  ERROR
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | "The following error status was produced while attempting to fetch products:
medusa-storefront    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
medusa-storefront    |
```